# Subsetting data frame in R based on two columns values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a a data frame with different genes expression levels as columns, and columns including which time point & which group the gene belongs to. I now want to get the gene expression values corresponding to a certain gene and group:

```
cpm[cpm$group=="dysglyc",colnames(cpm)==gene]
```

However, I also want to include a certain time point:

```
cpm[cpm$group=="dysglyc" && cpm$timepoint=="A1",colnames(cpm)==gene]
```

This does not work... Can someone help please?

Comment: with hust one & that will do it.

Comment: try `cpm[cpm$group=="dysglyc" & cpm$timepoint=="A1", "gene"]`

Comment: It's useful to run each of your conditional expressions separately to see which part of your overall expression isn't working as intended. Run `cpm$group=="dysglyc"`, `cpm$timepoint=="A1"`, and `cpm$group=="dysglyc" && cpm$timepoint=="A1"` to see if they return the logical vectors that you expected. When you _do_ resort to posting a question, please don't just say "it doesn't work" - you should describe what happens, and what you expected. A reproducible example also helps us help you.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe it, I must have typed something wrong, it works with only one &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that you use `data.table` library for usage of this kind with your data.frame indexed on both `group` and `timepoint`. You can achieve this like so:

```
cpm = data.table(cmp)  # Convert to data.table
setkeyv(cpm, c("group", "timepoint"))  # Set indexing variables.
```

You can then subset easily using the `i` expression in `data.table`. E.g.:

```
cpm["dysglyc"]  # Pull everything dysglyc
cpm[J("dysglyc", "A1")]  # Pull everything group=dysglyc and timepoint=A1
cpm[J("dysglyc", "A1"), gene]  # Use column gene within this subset etc.
```

You can get started with `data.table`'s vignette available as `vignette('data.table')`. If you a have a large dataset and need to do a bunch of groupby or split-apply-combine operations, the package would be an added bonus.

Comment: I have looked for something like this for a long time! Thank you.